# Download multiple pdf files from github as a zip file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

On a button click on the UI page, I am looking to allow user to download a number of pdf files

which reside inside a github repository.

I am able to connect to that repo and find the pdfs based on printing out `file.download_url`.

It prints out like:

> https://github.example.com/raw/company-org/repo_name/main/my-folder-name/file1.pdf?token=AAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEE

The second fetch call on `file.download_url` works too. Able to get a 200 OK response.

When I click the UI button, it results in intermediate issues as follows.

One of the following:

> 1. It is just stuck on loading on the UI page with loading.
>    2. Or downloads like this `Unconfirmed 646958.crdownload`.  
>    3. Or
>    downloads pdf.zip. But when I extract it, it is a single file (meant
>    to be 3) and gibberish.

I seem to be messing up the zip and download part.

Can I get some help with this pls. Tried with a npm package called `archiver` which produced same issues.

Overall just want to let user download all the pdf files as a zip from that github repo's specific folder.

User can then unzip and view all 3 pdf files on their machine.

P.S: Not married to current implementation. Happy to update it in any other way, be it UI or backend / use npm packages. Thanks.

My UI

```
const DownLoad = () => {
  const handleDownload = () => {
    const downloadUrl = `${apiDomain}/api/download`;
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = 'pdf.zip';
    a.click();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SomeButton
        onClick={handleDownload}
      >
        Click Me
      </SomeButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My Node JS backend

```
import express from 'express';
import zlib from 'zlib';
import util from 'util';

import { pipeline } from 'stream';

const router = express.Router();
const pipelineAsync = util.promisify(pipeline);

router.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
  const folderPath = 'some_path';
  const apiUrl = `https://github.example.com/api/v3/repos/${GITHUB_ORG}/${REPO_NAME}/contents/${folderPath}`;
  const zipFileName = 'pdf.zip';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${GITHUB_PAT_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    const files = await response.json();
    res.attachment(zipFileName);
    const compression = zlib.createGzip();

    try {
      const output = res;
      const filePromises = files.map(async (file) => {
        const fileResponse = await fetch(file.download_url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${GITHUB_PAT_TOKEN}`,
          },
        });
        const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(await fileResponse.arrayBuffer());
        compression.write(fileBuffer);
      });
      await Promise.all(filePromises);
      await pipelineAsync(compression, output);
      compression.end();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    res.status(200).send('zip file generated for download');
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(`Internal Server Error: ${e}`);
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @KJ But isn't that what I am doing. Looping the files and then compressing them. Or could you show an example pls.